# MVVMCross BindingContext is Null when not using MvxContentPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, syncfusion

I have an issue where several of my pages are using the `SfBackdropPage` control from Syncfusion. This control requires the page to have a base of `SfBackdropPage` and not the usual `ContentPage` otherwise it just won't work.

To make MVVMCross work, the page needs have a base such as `MvxContentPage`

You see where this is going ?

I opened a ticket with Syncfusion to see if they could work around this issue but basically they just said its not possible. So since I needed to have that control as part of the page I had to leave the base as it was.

How do I setup MVVMCross to work with these pages without having the page inherit from `MvxContentPage` ?

I've used the following in the `setup.cs` in the Android project:

```
protected override IMvxViewsContainer InitializeViewLookup(IDictionary<Type, Type> viewModelViewLookup)
{
    viewModelViewLookup.Add(typeof(SitesViewModel), typeof(SitesView));
    return base.InitializeViewLookup(viewModelViewLookup);
}
```

I can navigate to the page but I get a null reference exception due to the binding context not been set. I've tried to set this in the XAML but it requires a parameterless constructor but that's not possible as the view model uses Dependency Injection as it relies on these object been passed in.

Can anyone give any pointers, I'm still learning MVVMCross so hopefully I've just missed something.

XF: 4.8.0.1687
MVVMCross: 7.1.2

**UPDATE 1:**
I've tried to find something in the MVVMCross source to see how it does the setup for the binding context, but I've not found anything. So for now, I'm manually creating the binding context in the page code behind and using `Mvx.IocProvider.Resolve<>` to pass the required interfaces.

I'm not sure if this is the best to workaround this issue but it works. Maybe there is a better way ?

**UPDATE 2:**
It seems that update 1 route is no good as the doing this creates a new instance of the VM which is to be expected but an instance already exists which is created by the MVVMCross framework. The question is how do I get the VM instance from the code behind ? The only way I have found so far is to use `IMvxOverridePresentationAttribute` and the cast the request to `MvxViewModelInstanceRequest` which then allows access to the VM instance which I assign to the binding context. I may be better off creating another question as to the best approach for this method.

Comment: For a slightly cleaner solution, you can define a parameterless constructor in the VM and resolve the interfaces inside it. Then you can set the binding context in XAML. It's pretty much what you have in your update, but it moves the dependency resolution from the code behind to the VM.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Andrew, I had never thought of that. Just hoping some MVVMCross expert comes along and tells me there is a much better way to do this.